# Can I specify two attribute at once in D3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, attributes

I'm positioning my elements using the two *attr* lines (here it's circle, elsewhere, it might be something different).

```
graph1.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(_, i) { return i; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d; })
  .attr("r", "5")
  .attr("class", "dataPoint");
```

It's **veeery** common to specify both coordinates for each element. In fact, I can't imagine a sane case where it isn't. So I wonder if it's possible to specify both attributes at one, something like this pseudo-code.

```
...
//.attr("cx", function(_, i) { return i; })
//.attr("cy", function(d) { return d; })
.attr("[cx cy]", function(d,i) { return [i,d]; })
...
```

Since *cx* and *cy* are attributes, I'm assuming that CSSing them isn't an option.

Comment: *"In fact, I can't imagine a sane case "* -- I may be called insane then, but I do it every now and then. Many of these attributes default to zero placing the elements on the border or at the origin. This may significantly ease calculations, and you can translate them to their final position later on. In fact, even here in one of my answers on SO I have [built an example](/a/33400594/4235784) utilizing this. In it I use a `circle` having `r` as its only attribute as well as a `line` with just `y1` set to a value. Agreed, it is not really common, but it may be helpful from time to time.

Comment: @altocumulus Given my "substantial" experience from D3 spanning over about 5 days, I might stand corrected, hehe. Always good to see alternative approaches. Thanks for the link - I'll take a look in a few. Just to be clear, I meant no insult nor disrespect, of course. I hope that's abundantly clear.   :)

Comment: Since when has insanity ever become an insult ;-) This is IT, isn't it? Don't worry, all is fine! Just keep in mind that my comment is not restricted to D3 but is rather about properties of SVGs whatsoever. My answer, I linked to, is trying just that: finding a pure SVG-only solution without the need to fiddle with any scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object to create the input.

```
...
//.attr("cx", function(_, i) { return i; })
//.attr("cy", function(d) { return d; })
.attr({'cx':'100','cy':'100'})
...
```

Note that the quotes are optional if you use object notation, except for specifying a class attribute. In your case, it looks like this.

```
.attr({
  cx: function(_, i) { return i; },
  cy: function(d, _) { return d; }
})
```

Since you're probably going to use scaling methods, I'm not sure if it's improving the readability, though - perhaps you should move out the function declarations.

```
function posX(_, i) { return x(i); }
function posY(d, _) { return y(d); }
graph1.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("circle")
  .attr({ cx: posX, cy: posY })
  .attr("r", "5")
  .attr("class", "dataPoint");
```